# Tkinter program not responding

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I was tying to make a simple music player with python, its not finished yet, as the program stops responding when it goes into the play function. What is the problem and how to fix it ? There are no errors but a weird exit code - 805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)
Additional info-
when play button is pressed it goes into the pressed state without coming out again.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame
from tinytag import TinyTag
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import time

win = Tk()

def play():
    # when it goes to this function, it stops responding
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(t)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    to = MP3(t)
    print(to.info.length)
    time.sleep(to.info.length)
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(t1)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()


def stop():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pygame.mixer.init()

play_button = PhotoImage(file="C:/1 Files and Folders/SHARAN/Python/SVE atom/Images/Untitled.png")
stop_button = PhotoImage(file="C:/1 Files and Folders/SHARAN/Python/SVE atom/Images/stop.png")


# Button(win, image=pause_button, borderwidth=0).place(x=100, y=100)

Button(win, image=play_button, borderwidth=0, command=play).place(x=140, y=100)

# Button(win, image=next_button, borderwidth=0).place(x=220, y=100)

Button(win, image=stop_button, borderwidth=0, command=stop).place(x=180, y=100)

# Button(win, image=previous_button, borderwidth=0).place(x=260, y=100)

list_song = Listbox(win, width=60)
list_song.place(x=200, y=200)
list_song.insert(END, "C:/Users/cuber/Music/To/Lil Nas X-Old Town Road.mp3")
list_song.insert(END, "C:/Users/cuber/Music/Bad Computer - Disarray [Monstercat Release] (128kbps).mp3")
t = list_song.get(0)
t1 = list_song.get(1)


print(t)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: tkinter apps stop responding when their `mainloop()` is prevented from running. The `time.sleep(to.info.length)` in the `play()` function would do that.

Comment: can I define a variable to ```to.info.length``` and then call it in time function, would that work?

Comment: You can pause a tkinter app by calling the universal widget [`after()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) method with a delay time in  milliseconds, i.e. 1000ms = 1s, without the optional callback function argument.

Comment: So, ```win.after()``` instead of ```time.sleep()```

Comment: Note that `after()` wants milliseconds and `sleep()` wants seconds — the units of time are different.